# std::cout imbued with oddity

Tags: c++, locale, cout

Two days ago, I set out to code something that I thought would be very simple: format a date string as saved in a DATE field in mysql from "YYYY-MM-DD" to a user supplied format. Since then, I have been stuck in problems with locales.

```
#include <iostream>    
#include <ctime> 

std::string fdate(std::string date, std::string format) {
        char buf[50];
        int year, month, day;
        std::tm tm;
        sscanf(date.c_str(), "%d-%d-%d", &year, &month, &day);
        tm.tm_year = year - 1900;
        tm.tm_mon  = month - 1;
        tm.tm_mday = day;
//      std::cout << "std::cout locale: " << std::cout.getloc().name() << std::endl;
        strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), format.c_str(), &tm);
        return buf;
}


int main() {
        std::locale::global(std::locale(""));
        std::cout.imbue(std::locale());
        std::string format("%a %d %b %Y");
        std::string day("2018-04-14");
        std::string formatted_day = fdate(day, format);
        std::cout << "std::cout locale: " << std::cout.getloc().name() << std::endl;
        std::cout << day << "     => " << formatted_day << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

The above code outputs:

> std::cout locale: en_GB.utf8
>      2018-04-14     => ? 14 Apr 2018

Notice that "%a" is supposed to output the short English name of the day of the week, namely "Sun". Instead a "?" is output, because for some reasons that I do not understand, the locale information needed by strftime() is missing.

If I uncomment the line commented out in the method above, the output becomes:

> std::cout locale: en_GB.utf8
>      std::cout locale: en_GB.utf8
>      2018-04-14     => Sun 14 Apr 2018

Over the past two days, I have tried many different variations, but the code sample above highlights one occurrence that puzzles me a lot.
Why adding a std::cout statement within the method "fixes" the problem?
What better method is there to achieve what I originally set out to do?

**Edit:** actually 2018-04-14 is a Saturday! So, I am making another wrong assumption in my code. How to fill in the missing field of std::tm? Isn't there anything in the std library capable of computing the day of the week given a YYYY-MM-DD date?

Comment: Cannot reproduce with gcc 7.3.1. I get the expected results with `LC_ALL=en_GB.utf8` and the shown code, as is. Locale support has been historically problematic.

Comment: And as far as filling in the missing pieces -- date and calendar support in the standard C/C++ library is a bit weak. Many functional holes. Any serious work involving dates will probably need to use some special purpose library.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: Thanks for testing. I'm using g++ (Gentoo 6.4.0-r1 p1.3) 6.4.0. See my edit posted 8 seconds after your comment: does your test outputs "Sat" or "Sun"?

Comment: It outputs "Sun". `std::cout locale: en_GB.utf8 / 2018-04-14     => Sun 14 Apr 2018`.

Comment: Don't use `scanf()` to read a date.  Use `strptime()`.

Comment: `strptime()` will not solve the issue. It only initializes the parsed fields in `tm`, without computing the derived ones.